# how to find out the submenu item's name in this special case (for a shortcut)

Tags: keyboard, textedit

In TextEdit there is this submenu (see the image) that I want to define a shortcut for. 
I can't define a shortcut for the "Right to Left" item, I assume it's because there are actually 2 such items in the submenu, under different sections. So how do I uniquely identify this item? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indented menu items start with tabs, but there are still two of them.

`tell application "System Events" to tell process "TextEdit" to name of menu items of menu 1 of menu item "Writing Direction" of menu 1 of menu item "Text" of menu "Format" of menu bar 1`

You can specify some shortcuts like `Format->Indentation->Increase` in 10.8 (or `>Format>Indentation>Increase` in 10.7), but it doesn't help in this case.

[image]

You can enable shortcuts for changing writing direction in System Preferences:

[image]

Comment: thanks, this solves the problem by a different approach. I didn't get the highlighted part of your answer, could you elaborate? I'm using 1.6.8.

Comment: You can run it in AppleScript Editor to see the names of the menu items.

Comment: cool, thanks. the reply is `{"Paragraph", " Default", " Left to Right", " Right to Left", missing value, "Selection", " Default", " Left to Right", " Right to Left"}` though, so the problem still exists